# No enforcement for method signature

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-typings, enforcement

If I define a method inside an interface and then implement it later on, it's parameters types aren't being enforced if the Interface was using method signature (it works for property signature).

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-2e63e?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

it looks a lot like a bug, is it? is it intentional? is there a way to tackle it without changing all of our functions to property signatures?

it's different than this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51727721/typescript-interface-implementing-doesnt-check-method-parameters) since in the question, the interface's method accepts some parameter and the implementation can work without it (which is logical). But here the implementation expects to receive an expanded parameter which **doesn't exist** in the Interface

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript interface implementing doesn't check method parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51727721/typescript-interface-implementing-doesnt-check-method-parameters)

Comment: @r3dst0rm nope. in this situation the options in the parameters is getting less options and work with it, which is logical.
Here I want to receive expanded parameter which doesn't exist in the Interface

Comment: Please put the text of your [mcve] directly in the question; external links are a good supplement but should not replace a direct text version. See the guidelines on [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's intentional.  A little background about function parameters and variance (which you can skip if you already know this):

If I ask for a function that accepts a `string`, and you give me a function that accepts `unknown`, I will be happy.  I can safely pass that function a `string` and it will accept it because `string` is assignable to `unknown`.  This is *contravariance*, because the direction of assignability switches: `string` is assignable to `unknown`, therefore `(x: unknown) => void` is assignable to `(x: string) => void`.

Compare this to *covariance*, where the direction of assignability stays the same: `"foo"` is assignable to `string`, therefore is `(x: "foo") => void` assignable to `(x: string) => void`?  No, it's not.  If I ask for a function that accepts a `string`, and you give me a function that accepts only the string literal `"foo"`, I will probably be unhappy if I use it.  If I pass that function a `string` that doesn't happen to be `"foo"`, then the function will not accept it.

So it's type safe to check function parameters contravariantly, and not type safe to check them covariantly.  So what does TypeScript do?  Well, before TypeScript 2.6, the compiler actually allowed *both*.  That is, it checked all function and method parameters [*bivariantly*](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant).

Why would it do this?  One of the issues has to do with methods that modify an object.  Consider the example in the linked FAQ: the `push()` method of arrays.  We usually want an `string[]` to be assignable to `unknown[]`.  If I only read from such an array, this is perfectly safe.  I ask for an `unknown[]`; you give me a `string[]`; I read from it, pulling out `unknown` values (which happen to be `string` objects but that's fine).  But writing to the array is unsafe.  If I call `array.push(123)`, that should be fine if `array` is `unknown[]` but very bad if it is `string[]`.  If the parameter to `push()` were checked contravariantly only, this would enforce the safety, disallowing `string[]` to be assignable to `unknown[]`.  But, as they say in the FAQ, that would be "incredibly annoying".  Instead, they allow the unsafe-yet-convenient convention of allowing function and method parameters to vary both ways.

---

Back to the answer to this question: Luckily for those of us who like a little more type safety, TypeScript 2.6 introduced the [`--strictFunctionTypes` flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) which, when enabled, causes function parameter types to be checked only contravariantly instead of bivariantly.

But there's still that issue with `Array` and other built-in classes that are often used covariantly.  To prevent `--strictFunctionTypes` from being "incredibly annoying", the tradeoff is that *function* parameters are checked contravariantly, but *method* parameters are still checked bivariantly.  So as of TS2.6, the compiler cares about the difference between method signatures and function signatures when it comes to type checking parameters.

And so with the following interface:

```
interface Example {
    func: (x: string) => void;
    method(x: string): void;
}
```

You get the following behavior (in TS2.6+ with `--strictFunctionTypes` enabled):

```
const contravariant: Example = {
    func(x: unknown) { }, // okay!
    method: (x: unknown) => { } // okay!
}

const covariant: Example = {
    func(x: "foo") { }, // error!
    method: (x: "foo") => { } // okay!
}
```

Note that in `contravariant` and `covariant`,  `func` is *implemented* as a method and `method` is *implemented* as a function-valued property, but they are still *checked* according to the rules in the `Example` interface: `func` has a function signature and is checked strictly, and `method` has a method signature and is checked loosely.

---

So, is there a way to tackle it without changing all of your functions to property signatures?  Probably nothing great.  You might try to transform the signatures programmatically, like this:

```
type MethodsToFunctionProps<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: infer A) => infer R ? (...args: A) => R : T[K]
}
```

which works in this case:

```
const covariantFixed: MethodsToFunctionProps<Example> = {
    func(x: "foo") { }, // error!
    method: (x: "foo") => { } // error!
}
```

but there may be edge cases so I don't know if that's worth it to you.

---

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbFAbwChkzkYBXEBALmQAp16BnMKUAcwEpkBeAHzIAbgHtgAEwDcpclghgAFqIlNW7Lt3pjJMgL7FiCUSDbJj4KHGFwOccPQzZ8KPshLkK1BGuTUA1iCiAO4gvITIegA0yAD0scii-nAAngCEsmTySir0vgFBobyC7pFxCUmpGXrIhhZmxjZ2DmiYuAT87pleNL4ARDCion3hkTHxyNBQolAZntnKEnnMyANDI-xCETUTlenEBsRgKTgoALIKiywAKqIAYt5gwCYACtM4LAA810JuHuQAbQA0shQMh-BAUqIYMhrgBdejXYFwyboSAgCQsRgAOlxtk4LHooBg0GQAEFikJiaSAErIAD8OLxUAJ9Apm2QdMRyIOdRMDVETWA9jAd2A6AgS2QFxymNuDxoT1e7y+TnaEF+XU8VF6KzWw1G0XKkyg01m3QWuUYesGBo522NUxm1WIQA)